# C# property value unavailable in new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, properties, invoke

I'm having a text box with an event onchange which gets the length of the text as a buffer. Inside the callback function which I called `MessageCallback` I want to send this buffer as a parameter. However, as the parameter is passed inside a method which is being invoked in another thread, the property of the buffer is unavailable. How can I go around this?

To imagine what I'm trying to do, here are snippets of my code:

```
    private int buflen = 1500;
    private int Buflen
    {
        get { return this.buflen; }
        set { this.buflen = value; }
    }


    private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        //this.Buflen = textMessage.Text.ToString().Length;
        //MessageBox.Show(this.buflen.ToString());
        try
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    EndPoint epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textRemoteIp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textRemotePort.Text));
                    MessageBox.Show(this.Buflen.ToString()); // returns 0 ?
                    int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref epRemote);
```

...

```
    private void textMessage_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Buflen = textMessage.Text.Length;
        MessageBox.Show(Buflen.ToString());
    }
```

So what I'm asking is how to make the property `Buflen` visible inside the newly created thread?

Comment: You forgot to specify the language used...

Comment: I am sorry, it's C# and the .NET 4 framework

Answer (score -1):

1. make the property synchronized
2. make the property public

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Do you mean that I have to do either one of these or both?

Comment: Start with making it public only, but I suppose it would be better if you will make it synchronized too. Every time two threads read/write the same variable, it should be synchronized to avoid race.

Comment: making it public does not work in my case. I suppose the issue is that I'm using a callback function and with each iteration a new thread is started. I'm still trying to accomplish a decent solution, I would appreciate if someone could give me an example on how to synchronize the threads. Another issue I'm dealing with is that if I create a new thread in the MainWindow method it is not accessible inside the invoker. I really need some help or guidance here I'm reading about thread synchronization but I'm getting lost into this, I got the basics however I'm unable to apply this into the invoker